# I am getting error the locale ' ' is no known locale in magento

Tags: php, magento, report, locale

I  am getting error  the locale ' '  is no known locale in Magento. when I    go  under report >> sales >> order report .

[image: here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error shows when your language is not find in locale

F:eg in DB core_config_data in fifth record path for (general/locale/code) have value de_De which not found in your locale

use available language and this will resolve in my case this error shows on home page